# Image search does not work across different systems using pyautogui python?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I was automating software installation using python's pyautogui model. So, I crop some images from installation screen like for clicking next, accept the terms and conditions. Using image search I am able to locate the image on the screen and able to click on the right areas. Works fine in my system.
However, the script does not work in other systems as image search is unsuccessful. May be because image is cropped in my system and being searched in other system. The resolutions of both the systems are same but the screen size is different(like 15 inch, 17 inch). My question was does the function locateOnScreen is compatible across different machines? How can I resolve this problem given that I need to deploy this automation across multiple systems in the company? The code is pasted below:

```
import os
import time
import pyautogui
from pywinauto.application import Application
fsv = Application(backend="win32").start("sandra_24.61.exe")
while(1):
    s = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("C:\\WV_Project\\testcaseAutomation\\images\\ok.png")
    if (s==None):
        print("wait for 1 sec for ok button to come")
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        pyautogui.click(s.left,s.top)
        print("Ok clicked")
        break
while(1):
    s = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("C:\\WV_Project\\testcaseAutomation\\images\\acceptRadio.png")
    if (s==None):
        print("wait for 1 sec for accept radio button to come")
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        x=s.left
        y=s.top
        pyautogui.click(s.left,s.top)
        print("accept clicked")
        break;
time.sleep(2)
x = x+366
y=y+78
pyautogui.click(x,y)
print("next clicked")
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.click(x,y)
time.sleep(2)
print("next clicked")
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.click(x,y)
print("next clicked")
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.click(x,y)
time.sleep(2)
print("next clicked")
pyautogui.click(x,y)
time.sleep(2)
print("next clicked")
pyautogui.click(x,y)
print("install clicked")
time.sleep(50)
while(1):
    time.sleep(2)
    try:
        x,y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("C:\\WV_Project\\testcaseAutomation\\images\\finish.png")
        pyautogui.click(x,y)
        break
    except:
        print("Exception occurred")
print("Sandra is successfully installed.")
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can assume! The problem is with image resolution.
In my company, I also have a robot that automates some complex task. All the monitors here are same but still, I was facing some trouble matching images. Cropped image from one PC was not working on another. So what I am doing right now is using "SNIPPING TOOLS" to take screenshots in every pc. This solves the problem easily but this solution takes time. If you are not using more than 10 or 20 different PC's then this solution may help.

If the problem exists then you may try by reducing the **CONFIDENCE LEVEL** like below:

```
x,y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("C:\\WV_Project\\testcaseAutomation\\images\\finish.png", grayscale=True, confidence=.5)
```

Try using different confidence levels.
You will also need OPENCV for using CONFIDENCE.
use "pip install opencv-python" for installing OPENCV from command prompt.

Comment: Nopes this also does not work...also reducing the confidence level , image search gets nasty, means other part of the screen will match the criteria . But anyways will try that out once again. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Nopes this does not work yet, when I give confidence=0.5, it matches other image instead. And for me taking snip is not possible as I don't know beforehand what kind of PC i will get.

Comment: @Sarwan Have you tried with some other confidence values like 0.9 or 0.8...? 
If none of them works then could you please try another shortcut solution by using PYAUTOGUI KEYBOARD FUNCTIONS **TAB** to navigate the focus to certain button and then hit the **ENTER**? you can hit multiple tabs for navigation and then finally hit enter like below:
`pyautogui.press('enter')`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the resolution if you make script in `1366x768`and trying in 1920x1080 it will never work because you need to add new image

there are two ways you can use:

1:> replace the image

2:> add the x,y position

**Way:**

```
xy = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('your directory', grayscale=True, confidence=.5)
pg.click(xy)
```

3:> you can capture icon with inspect

**you can also right click andd click on inspect and go to applications and find that image in image folder save it and it will work on all screen**

Comment: its the same resolution machines.